# How to pass System.Action parameter with lambda expressions for ForEach?

Tags: vb.net, lambda, foreach, compiler-errors, uipath

When trying to use a lambda expression instead of the `AddressOf` operator, with a parameter for `ForEach` sub I am getting the following error:

> Statement lambdas cannot be converted to expressions trees

This is the `AddressOf` code, which works:

```
lista.ForEach(new Action(Of String)(AddressOf Console.WriteLine))
```

This is the lambda code which produces the error:

```
lista.ForEach(new Action(Of String)(Function(x) x = "teste")
```

The method `ForEach` is being invoked so the `Action` needs to be passed as a parameter.

Can anyone could help me with this or tell me whether it's possible or not?

Comment: `lista.ForEach(new Action(Of String)(Sub(x) x = "teste")`

Comment: Thank you Fabio, but I get the same compilation error. "Statement lambda..."

Comment: Next line will compile ok -> `lista.ForEach(new Action(Of String)(Sub(value) Console.WriteLine(value)))`. So you can even remove `new Action...` and pass just lambda there:  `lista.ForEach(Sub(value) Console.WriteLine(value))`

Comment: What is the type of `lista`?

Comment: When I use `Console.WriteLine(variable)` it works fine, I've already been able to use it like that. But when I try to perfom some process with the variable like `variable = "teste"`, I get the error.

`lista` is a `List<string>` type:

TypeSystem.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, your problem is this:

```
lista.ForEach(new Action(Of String)(Function(x) x = "teste")
```

`ForEach` is a Method that does not return a value as a result of the operation.

Change it to:

```
lista.ForEach(new Action(Of String)(Sub(x) x = "teste"))
```

Although, I do not like that method signature at all, you are over-complicating this action you need performed.

Considering the ForEach Method ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx)) accepts `Action<T>`, there is no need to declare `new Action(of String)`.  All you need to focus on is the Lambda Express you wish to pass for the List/Array to execute for each element

Good Read to understand the basics [VB's Lambda Expression Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions)

With that, try this pattern instead:

```
lista.ForEach(Sub(x) x = "teste")
```

or

```
lista.ForEach(Function(x) x = "teste")
```